# .env file not updating in local environment in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I do have a .env file in my react project and using `dotenv` package to read the environment variables. I did a console log of the environment variables. I had initialized few variables in the beginning in .env file and was being read perfectly.

Later I changed some data in the .env file and restarted the local server, but new changes were not being reflected. EVEN after deleting the .env file and starting the server, the same old variables are loaded.
I know it's a cache issue but could not figure out a way to reset it.

I am using `npm start` command to start the server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Use REACT_APP prefix

You need to declare variables with **REACT_APP** prefix as per the **[documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)**.

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_API_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
```

And similarly, access them with the **prefix** in your code

```js
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID);
```

**Note:** You need to restart the dev server every time you update the env file to consume the changes.

Comment: I did initiate every variable with REACT_APP_ but no effects when I change variables data or remove some variables

Comment: @AnkitShah you would need to show code for better debugging. Also, what's the name of file you're using for variables?

Comment: Got it right, it was some cache issue. i used --reset-cache with the start command and restarting the system helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Changing env variables requires to restart node server to take the new values.

But sometimes , it doesn't work , so you mush apply a cache reset.

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few random times before, and unfortunately, the answers above didn't fix it for me. I noticed if I changed the .env variable e.g. from `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL` to `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL_2` it changes, which proves it is some sort of weird caching issue.

What works for me is just committing all your changes, push to Github, delete the whole repo and re-clone it ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache
```

Then:

```
press 'r'
```

To debug, make sure you are logging the variable after it is called:

```
import { REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL_LOCAL } from '@env';

let baseURL = REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL_LOCAL;

console.log('this is my variable ------>', baseURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this trick on Github:

> Manually edit the file importing react-native-dotenv by either adding an empty line or whitespace will work.

https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv/issues/24#issuecomment-581125204